# What are the sources for old (1998 or earlier) satellite or aerial photos of the (southern) Netherlands?

Tags: satellite, aerial-photography, data-source

Our municipality says that our garden is too big, according too the cadastre. If we can prove the situation has been already there for twenty years, then they won't charge us for the extra space our garden takes in.

As this is the case, I'm looking to prove this. I have already tried Google Earth and Google Earth Engine, where the first didn't go back enough and the latter wasn't detailed enough. 
So I am looking for any source of detailed satellite/aerial photos of the southern part of the Netherlands. They don't have to be free per se, altough it is a pro.

After request: the garden is about 40m² and the dispute is about an area of 10m² therefore 1pixel to 1m² resolution would be sufficient

Comment: It would help if you mentioned the minimum resolution you require. How big is the garden?

Comment: The garden is about 40m² and the issue about an area of 10m²

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer by @bugmenot123, you could try the Kadaster
https://www.kadaster.nl/-/luchtfoto-s

Answer (score 1):

You can find a catalog of official, historic, aerial imagery at http://nationaalgeoregister.nl/geonetwork/srv/dut/catalog.search#/search?facet.q=keyword%2Fluchtfoto

Comment: Altough very complete, the pictures date back untill 2004

Comment: well, I don't speak dutch but if you search for Luchtfoto you also get older ones.

Answer (score -2):

You can search [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). They list a variety of sources, both free and commercial.